# Java unexpected concurrent result

Tags: java, concurrency

While testing concurrency, I found something unexpected.

Concurrency was controlled using concurrentHashMap and AtomicLong.

```java
public class HumanRepository {

    private final static Map<Long, Human> STORE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private AtomicLong sequence = new AtomicLong();

    public void save(Human human) {
        STORE.put(sequence.incrementAndGet(), human);
    }

    public int size() {
        return STORE.size();
    }


    public Long getSeq() {
        return sequence.get();
    }
}
```

I tested saving in multiple threads.

```java
    @Test
    void name() throws NoSuchMethodException, InterruptedException {
        final int threads = 3_500;
        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        final CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(threads);
        final HumanRepository repository = new HumanRepository();

        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            try {
                es.execute(() -> repository.save(new Human("aa")));
            } finally {
                count.countDown();
            }
        }

        count.await();

        System.out.println("seq = " + repository.getSeq());
        System.out.println("size = " + repository.size());
    }
```

I tested it with 3500 threads simultaneously. The result I expected is 3500 for both seq and size.

But sometimes I get seq=3499, size=3500.
That's weird. It is strange that seq does not come out as 3500, and even though the size is 3500, it does not make sense that seq is 3499.

I don't know why the data number and seq in the map are not the same and 3500 is not coming out.

** If you do `Thread.sleep(400L);` after `count.await();`, surprisingly, the value of seq is 3500

[image]

Comment: "But sometimes I get seq=3499, size=3500" - you haven't shown anything that would provide any *output* all. We don't know how you're observing those results. Can you write this as a [mcve] so that we can just compile, run, and see the results?

Comment: Sorry, I've added more.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: having 3500 threads for 3500 tasks is usually not a great idea, unless they are **extremely** I/O bound **and** you have tons of I/O capacity as well. For CPU-bound tasks you want on the order of the number of your cores threads and for I/O bound tasks you want more, but most systems won't realistically be able to do 3500 parallel database stores in an efficient manner.

Comment: The first obvious problem is not even related to threads. Why is `STORE` `static` but `sequence` is not? If you only have test cases covering the existence of one `HumanRepository` instance, you obviously have insufficient test coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually waiting for all tasks to complete. Which means that if you get the 3500/3500 output, it's by chance.

Specifically, you decrease the countdown latch *on the main thread* after scheduling the job, instead of *inside of the job, once it's done*. That means your countdownlatch is basically just another glorified loop variable that doesn't do any inter-thread communication. Try something like this instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        es.execute(() -> {
          repository.save(new Human("aa"));
          count.countDown();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling count.countDown() outside the thread executing the HumanRepository.save(). So its possible that the main thread is not synchronized for the completion of the threads.

So you may see the results of repository.getSeq() while one thread is running. Can you try with the following code?

```
        final int threads = 3_500;
        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        final CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(threads);
        final HumanRepository repository = new HumanRepository();

        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            try {
                es.execute(() -> {
                    repository.save(new Human("aa"));
                    count.countDown();
                });
            } finally {
                
            }
        }

        count.await();

        System.out.println("seq = " + repository.getSeq());
        System.out.println("size = " + repository.size());
```